# Write modbus register with pymodbus

Tags: python, python-2.7, modbus

I'm new to programming.

I need to write modbus registers using python and I have no experience with pymodbus.

What is the way to actually start and communicate with a modbus server?
Im able to read the registers from this modbus server using a software I found on the internet.

How can I read the registers and write to them using pymodbus module? I literally dont know where to start.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: modbus has some section such as tcp, rtu, udp protocol, [this](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a full document and they have many example.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

try:            
    client = ModbusClient(host='IP',port='502')
    request = client.read_holding_registers(0x00,5,unit=1)
```